# How do I add a default value to a variable and store in the database in django?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I'm very new to the Django framework. I've started working with models and forms in django. I'm facing a problem in storing values to a database.

I want to get something like this.

```
from django.db import models

class attempt(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    department = "Software Development"
```

Now I want to store the variable `department` in the database. Where for every entry of object of attempt `name` will be entered by the user but `department` remains the same.

And is stored something like the below-given format in the database

```
id: 1
name: "John Shelby"
department: "Software Development"
```

Edit 2:
Now can I do something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class attempt(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    def function1(str):
        return(str+" Hello World")
    x = function1(name)
    department = models.Charfield(max_length=100,default=x,editable=False)
```

Comment: It makes no sense to store something in the database, if the value is each time the same.

Comment: I asked this as an example. I am taking a pdf document as an input from the user using 
`models.FileField()`. And I have the code to extract the data from it. But I have no clue how to save it into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `default`, [here's the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default) but basically what you want is:

```python
department = models.Charfield(max_length=100, default="Software Development", editable=False)
```

This will make it that each time the model is created it will give it the default value in the `department` field. To prevent changes to said default value, I added the `editable=False` tag. Remove it in case you want to add other departments but have `"Software Development"` as the default one if no department is set.

Comment: Thank you Barraguesh. Can I do this with my code


`from django.db import models`

`class attempt(models.Model):`
   `name = models.TextField(max_length=200)`
    `def fun1(name):`
        `return(name+"some string")`
   `x = fun1(name)`
   `department = models.Charfield(max_length=100, default=x, editable=False)`

Comment: @TharunTeja please update (edit) the original question with that question and code because it's hard to read code from a comment!

Comment: @TharunTeja The class is for models, functions can be implemented in the model, but have to be related to it, check out this example from the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#model-methods. Also, if my answer is what you were looking for, you can select it as such with the tick.